# Possible heap corruption issue when deleting an object

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I'm working on a framework and have run into an issue. I noticed that I was leaking memory by not deleting an object. When I tried to delete this object just before exiting the application I get an error, this one to be exact:

[image: Error on closing the application]

After I got this I grabbed [Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20028)

When running the code it set a breakpoint on the following piece of code:

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR tPfd = { 
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), 
    1, 
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA, 
    32, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 
    0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 
    24, 
    0, 
    0,
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
    0, 
    0, 0, 0
};

unsigned int tFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(g_WindowContext, &tPfd);
if( !tFormat ) {
    LOG( CRITICAL, "Pixelformat could not be choosen." );
    return false;
}
```

It set a breakpoint on the line with "ChoosePixelFormat(g_WindowContext,&tPfd);" and had the following 'explanation' for it:

> VERIFIER STOP 00000301: pid 0x3689C: Invalid TLS index used for current stack trace.
>
> `FFFFFFFF : Invalid TLS index.`
> `0000ABBA : Expected lower part of the index.`
> `00000000 : Not used.`
> `00000000 : Not used.`

I don't really get what is going on, the lines above these pieces of code are as follows:

```
g_Window = CreateWindowEx (
    0,
    PROJECT_NAME,                          // window class
    PROJECT_NAME,                          // window title
    tStyle,                          // visibility settings
    tX, tY,
    tW, tH,
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    tWindowClass.hInstance, 
    NULL
);

if(!g_Window) {
    LOG( CRITICAL, "Window could not be created." );
    return false;
}

g_WindowContext = GetDC(g_Window);
if( !g_WindowContext ) {
    return false;
}
```

The variables used here are:

```
HDC                     g_WindowContext;
HWND                    g_Window;
```

The object I am trying to delete is nothing special, the object is not corrupt while the application is running. I can use the object, I've tried using all its functions and they all work as expected time after time. Just when I try to delete the object at the end it gives the error message. The object is deleted just below the main application loop when everything is cleaned up. Nothing is using it at this point nothing seems to be the problem, when setting a breakpoint the pointer to the object itself is valid as well.

If anybody would be able to help me it would be greatly appreciated, if you need anymore information or pieces of code please let me know.

Comment: It's not clear to me which is the object you are deleting?

Comment: Could you show us the places where you create and delete the object?

Comment: The first place I would look is writing to an array at a negative index inside that object.  Just a hunch.

Comment: The object I am deleting is way after this code. This is part of the initialization of the window. I am deleting it literally just before I return 0 at the end of int main()

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I've been looking at this code for the past hours, I've been over it stepping through it. The object holds a 2d buffer of unsigned integers at a certain size, 640x480 at the moment but this is changeable. It has a width, height and pitch ( which equals the width.) I can access the 2D buffer just fine, read and writes work fine, plus I can display it onscreen perfectly. Just at the moment of deleting it goes wrong somewhere, my colleague and I are guessing there is a heap corruption somewhere but until now nothing has been found.

Comment: @Yonathan Klijnsma: It's common for a debug heap to put "no-mans-land" before and after dynamically located memory.  If you accidentally write out of bounds, it'll probably write in the no-mans-land, which means the program will work fine... until you try to delete it.  Then the debug heap manager will see that the no-mans-land values were changed, and report an error.  Since you have "damage before an allocation" caught on delete, this is the first place I'd look.  Place an assert right before all array access, just to be safe.

Comment: and to be clear, that _is_ a stab in the dark, or else I'd post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I know, I've been 'stabbing' in the dark for the past hours. I've tried your approach with the Assert() on accessing the array, nothing it still seems to be in a valid range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem, the last buffer I was deleting was buffer in video ram, I obviously can't delete this one. No heap corruption going on at all just a logical thinking flaw.

Thank you to the people that tried to answer this one and help me.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you try deleting the object right after you've created it and then exiting the program immediately? If you've not got masses of code in your project, just try shuffling that delete / exit further along the line until it starts going pop again. You can speed up this process by divide-and-conquering through all the executed code to home in on the source of the corruption.

Can you show us precisely where the crash happens? A complete example would help us diagnose the fault but without seeing that, it's very difficult to narrow it down any further.

Comment: Seeing its almost 1am I'll leave that for tomorrow, I'll try moving the delete further down until it starts giving me messages again, nice tip, thanks! I'll report tomorrow if I've located the error to a certain section of code. The code-base is quite big but its all made in modules so I can just turn them off one by one or delete the object in between the modules.

Comment: Well it seems right after allocation I can't delete it, already the error message pops up. I allocate it as follows:
`g_Surface = new Surface( SCRWIDTH, SCRHEIGHT, (Pixel*)g_FrameData, tPitch);` And the constructor code:
`Surface::Surface( int a_Width, int a_Height, Pixel* a_Buffer, int a_Pitch ) :
 m_Width( a_Width ),
 m_Height( a_Height ),
 m_Buffer( a_Buffer ),
 m_Pitch( a_Pitch )
{
}`

And the data members of the surface class:
`Pixel* m_Buffer;` 
`int m_Width, m_Height, m_Pitch;`

Comment: g_FrameData is a UINT8* and is pointed to the correct data as follows: `g_FrameData = (UINT8*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, GL_WRITE_ONLY_ARB);`

Answer (score 1):

Your objects are on the stack - and therefore do not require deleting. For `delete` to be required you need to have used `new` in the firet place.

So where is the `new` and the `delete` in your code.

Comment: `g_Surface = new 2DSurface( SCRWIDTH, SCRHEIGHT, (Pixel*)g_FrameData, tPitch);`

About 30 lines below the code I showed mainly because of Application Verifier. I delete it here:

 `delete g_Surface;`
 `return g_MSG.wParam;`
`}`

Which are the last lines of the main entrypoint.

Answer (score -1):

Your original question included a dump with the line "VERIFIER STOP 00000301: pid 0x3689C: Invalid TLS index used for current stack trace. "

If VERIFIER is Application Verifier, then maybe this is the cause:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842901

Symptom: When you use Windows Application Verifier to verify a custom-built program, it may stop responding or crash.

If you create a dump file, the file includes an entry for an access violation in OpenGL32!InitializeThread+043.

Cause: This problem occurs when OpenGL creates a table entry in a thread local storage (TLS) slot in the overflow area. However, Windows Application Verifier assumes that all TLS slots that are used by OpenGL are in the primary area, not in the overflow area. This causes Windows Application Verifier to generate an access violation.